# Rails | How to see live server log in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, server, unicorn, production-environment

How to see the live server log in production like it is shown in development?

[image: Server log in development]

My app is on digitalOcean, if that helps. I am using unicorn as my production server.

When I do `tail -f log/production.log`, I can just see some migration info like this, but not the live requests info along with the SQL queries being run.

[image]

Also in my production.rb, I changed `config.log_level` to `:debug`

Comment: I have the same question, awaiting an answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these lines of code into `config/environments/production.rb`:

```
Rails.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)

config.logger = ActiveSupport::Logger.new("log/#{Rails.env}.log")
```

Reference:

[This article for more info on logger](https://stackify.com/rails-logger-and-rails-logging-best-practices/)